# Rolling body with friction

Tags: rotational-dynamics, friction, dissipation

Will a body executing pure rolling on a rough surface stop, neglecting air drag and other heat losses but not friction? If yes, due to which friction it will stop, static or kinetic and how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will a pure rolling cylinder stop on a rough surface?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321658/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a perfect/ideal cylinder (or a sphere, disc, ring, etc) pure rolls, the velocity of the lowermost point is zero (condition for pure rolling). As the relative velocity between the surfaces at the point of contact is zero, there is no "kinetic" friction (if there is no external force, there will be zero static friction).

Therefore, the cylinder will continue to roll forever in your case.

Comment: You asked the exact same question 22 days ago! This is a duplicate of your question.

Comment: But i dont know how to mark duplicate.

Comment: You can post a comment, drawing attention to the question which this duplicates. Or you can flag the question for the attention of a moderator, pointing out that the question is a duplicate.

Comment: Oh thanks for telling me I will follow these for sure.