# A wheel is rolling up the (horizontal) street. Will it roll forever with the same speed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, work, friction

A wheel is rolling up the street (which is "horizontal", not an incline). The center of mass of the wheel has velocity V in the forward direction, relative to the ground. (Let's ignore air friction).

1. My understanding is that at any given moment, *the point at the top of the wheel*
   will have velocity V *relative to the car*, and thus will have velocity 2V *relative to the ground*. Is this correct?
2. Will the wheel continue to roll forever in the same speed?
3. We know that the wheel is using static friction from the ground to move forward. That means there's a force acting on the wheel, and therefore it has an acceleration. If the answer to question 2 to is "yes" - than how can the wheel have constant velocity while it is accelerating? It's a contradiction. Please explain the flaws in my logic

Comment: I assume the street is a perfect vacuum. Plus all the other little foibles such as the materials involved are perfectly non-conductive, non-magnetic, all that ideal jazz.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/294427/2451 and links therein.

Comment: "We know that the wheel is using static friction from the ground to move forward" This is simply not true. If it was true, then nothing would be able to move in space where there are no roads or friction. It is momentum that keeps things moving forward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all bodies are rigid, then the wheel will roll with constant velocity forever. There is no friction at all because the point of contact is stationary relative to the ground and there is nothing else that would otherwise cause slip. Therefore, the net force is zero. Friction only acts when the wheel attempts to slip. In other words, if, without friction, $v$ would otherwise be different from $r\omega$, then friction will act in the opposite direction to attempt to close the gap. This is how a motorized wheel works. Starting from rest, we have $v=0$, but if there were no friction, the driving torque would result in $r\omega \gt 0$. So friction acts to increase $v$ and the wheel is driven forward. This is consistent with the behavior of friction in any other case. Note that the converse is not true: no-slip does not imply no friction.

If the bodies are not rigid, then the weight will cause some deformation of the ground and a net force backwards, reducing the speed. This force is not friction but rolling resistance.

Comment: Thanks. So if there's no friction involved, as you say, because the lower point of the wheel is stationary relative to the ground: how is static friction connected to all this? I keep reading that static friction is what allows a car to move at all.

Comment: @AvivCohn See my edited answer. Stationary does not alone imply no friction. Rather, it is whether it would otherwise, without friction, violate the no-slip condition, $v=r\omega$. If it does then friction will act to try to restore it. If the required friction is less than the static threshold, then the no-slip will be preserved. If not then slip will occur.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus It is evident that you do not understand anything about this at all. The free wheel can keep rolling with constant velocity because there is **no friction**. The driven wheel moves forward due to friction. That's why cars cannot accelerate on frictionless surfaces.

Comment: Well, never mind. It is not your job to lecture me. I will delete the post and comments so as to err on the safe side and not confuse anyone.